# Python pyautogui typewrite prints ~ in place of # on web page

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am facing a problem with printing the # symbol in a textbox on a webpage with **Python pyautogui library**. I am not able to print # (it prints ~ in a text box on a web page):

**Input Example**

*my_string = "Here is an example for # symbol"*

*pyautogui typewrite (my_string)*

**Output**

*Here is an example for ~ symbol*

**Troubleshooting steps tried and additional information:**

1. String is printed correctly with a # symbol in the command prompt if I use print (my_string)
2. I tried using ASCII character code Chr(35), but it still prints ~ and not #. Both chr(35) and Chr(126) produce ~ character only.
3. Tried changing keyboard language in Windows OS from UK English to US English (My laptop is the UK built)
4. I can type manually the # symbol in a text box on the web page. Text box accepts # as input. I can copy # symbol and paste # symbol manually in the text box.
5. Both # and ~ are on the same key in my laptop. Pressing Shift + # would generate ~ symbol. I tried the hotkey function and that didn't work.
6. I tried repr(a_string) function, but no help.
7. Tried Edge and Chrome browsers, same result.
8. I have Python 3.10.1 on Windows 10 OS.

I would appreciate it if someone can help in identifying the issue and suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Pyautogui tries to figure out which keys have to be shifted by using a hard coded list. This does not (yet) take the keyboard set-up into account. To correct it you can change this line (line 530) in the **init**.py file of pyautogui:

```
return character.isupper() or character in set('~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?')
```

Just remove the # character from it and it should work.

Comment: funciona perfecto. La ubicacion del archivo en windows 10 La ubicacion del archivo en windows
...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\_init_.py